# How do I manage to use "addCondition" (Yii1) when i have 3 tables

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

Well, I have 3 tables: Products, Stores and Alerts.
Table alerts have the product_id and table products have the store_id. I have made a model relation so I can get an array with the data of the 3.

The problem is, I need to add a condition where it would only return alerts where client_id (on table Stores) is equal to the id of the client trying to access the data.

```
$clientidx = $clientlist->idx;
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = 'product';
$criteria->with = 'product.store';
$criteria->addCondition('product.store.client_idx = :client_idx');
$criteria->params[':client_idx'] = $clientidx;
$openalerts = Openalert::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Why can't I make the condition see `product.store.client_idx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In condition you should not use relation alias (`product.store`), but table alias. If you want to add condition for `client_idx` column in `store` table, you need:

```
$criteria->addCondition('store.client_idx = :client_idx');
```

---

Also this:

> ```
> $criteria->with = 'product';
> $criteria->with = 'product.store';
> ```

`$criteria->with = 'product'` has no effect, since you're overwriting this property immediately. If you want to set multiple relations, you need to pass array to `$with`. `['together' => true]` will also ensure that correct JOIN is created for query, so your condition will work correctly:

```
$criteria->with = [
    'product',
    'product.store' => ['together' => true],
];
```

Comment: This definitely worked and enlighted me about how to use it better. Thank you.